# Why is Panel OLS in Python giving me the error 'dependent and exog must have the same number of observations' when they are the same length?

Tags: python, runtime-error, panel-data, linearmodels

I'm trying to use Panel OLS from linearmodels, but get a message saying that the endogenous and exogenous variables aren't the same length. According to the code in the PanelOLS function, `y.shape[0] != x.shape[0]`, but when I print both shapes it's the same length.

Both `x` and `y` are multiindex df using this format:

```
mi_data = data.set_index(['fcode', 'year'])
```

Is there something I'm missing that's particular to Panel OLS?

y variable is UPT, x is treatUberX or treatGTNotStd

Data snapshot---there's also city and state, both strings, that were not able to be captured in the shot:

[dataframe screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJTMv.png)

Comment: Can you share an excerpt of the data you are working with?

Comment: Updated! Let me know if there's anything else that would be helpful

Comment: Can you open an issue on the linearmodels tracker?  This error comes up a few times and it is not helpful.